# "Giving up all its interests in the olive oil business" - meaning of "interests"

Tags: meaning-in-context

From the Godfather:

> Michael: The Corleone family's thinking of ***giving up all its interests***
>   in the olive oil business and settling out here.

I'm not sure if I follow what he said correctly so I'd like to ask first if it even make sense. If so, what is the meaning of **give up interests**? The **give up** phrasal could mean to stop doing something that you do regularly or to stop thinking or believing something. But how it can be tied with **interests**?

I'd say **We give up all our interests in <something>** means that we have no interests in that <something>.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Interests*, in this case, means "shares, rights, or title in the ownership of [...] a commercial [...] undertaking" (meaning #6 in this [dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/interests) definition, and related also to meaning #5)

*Giving up* those interests, in this case, implies selling their share of ownership in any and all ventures in the olive oil business.